# EmberJS - set default value of Select View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to set the default value for a select view in a form. The form has a list of countries set in the `controller` and this is used as the `contentBinding` for the Select.

However, the actual value of this select comes from the route's `model`. So I have to populate the Select with values from a different property in the controller and then set the current model as the default value.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/darus/2/

The 3 country options are "Asutria", "Australia" and "Canada". Now I want to set "Australia" as the default. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{view Ember.Select
      class="contactCountry"
      contentBinding="countryOptions"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      selectionBinding="address.id"      
      value = selectedCountry.id
      }}

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  countryOptions : [
    {id: 1, name:"Austria"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "Australia"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "Canada"}
  ],
  selectedCountry : {
    id: 2
  }
});
```

Its all explained right here in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html)

Comment: Thank you. I went through the docs, not sure how I missed it.